# How to change python 2d list items, when they met a criterial?

Tags: python, list

For example I have this list:

```
 m = [ 
['  ', '  ', ' X'], 
['  ', '  ', ' '], 
['  ', '  ', ' '], 
]
```

I wish to use the while function to check if a certain place of the list is empty, then change the value to E, and go right - if that place is also empty, but if not, then go down. And if both side are not empty, then change the current value to END
So far I have this:

```
 while i<len(m) and j<len(m):
  i = 0
  j = 0
  if m[i][j+1]==' ':
    j == j+1
    for i,item in enumerate(m):
      for j,item in enumerate(m):
        m[i][j] == 'E'
  elif m[i+1][j] == ' ':
    i== i+1
    for i,item in enumerate(m):
       for j,item in enumerate(m):       m[i][j] == 'E'
  else:
    for i,item in enumerate(m):
      for j,item in enumerate(m):
        m[i][j] == ' END '
```

In the end, when I let it print out my new list, it won't do that, and it doesn't change the values. What did I do wrong?

Thanks for your help!

I expect this at the end:

```
 m = [ 
[' E ', ' E ', ' X'], 
['  ', ' E ', ' E'], 
['  ', '  ', ' '], 
]
```

Comment: Can you please provide expected output

Comment: `==` is not an assignment operator, it's a comparison

Comment: you also need to remove those double `for` loops everywhere

Comment: and move `i=j=0` out of the `while` loop

Comment: ... and break once the END is reached

Comment: ... and check for out of bounds before checking the value right/down

Answer (score 1):

I think you overcomplicated your attempt a bit. What you should ideally do is only calculate/edit one point per loop, then set up the variables ready for the next loop.

Once you done that, you can basically simplify the instructions down to "can I move right?" and "can I move down?".

```
x = y = 0
while m[x][y] == '  ':
    m[x][y] = 'E'

    try:
        # Attempt to move right
        if m[x][y+1] == '  ':
            y += 1

        # Attempt to move down
        elif m[x+1][y] == '  ':
            x += 1

        # Stuck
        else:
            m[x][y] = 'END'
            break

    # Reached the edge of the list
    except IndexError:
        break
```